# Abbreviated form of Java getter/setter field methods

Tags: java

Im curious if there exists an abbreviation form for getter/setter methods of objects

```
SimpleObject oSimple = new SimpleObject();
oSimple.setCounterValue(oSimple.getCounterValue() + 1);
```

like one for simple datatypes

```
int counter = 0;
counter += 2;
```

**Info**

The getter/setter methods are required.

**Addition**

If there isn't a language feature thats support the idea, what is the most convenient way to deal with that in context of good and clean code?

Comment: You can do this in Scala but not in Java.

Comment: For your additional question, `lombok` prevents you from having to declare getters and setters (so that you only have to declare attributes in your beans) but you will still have to explicitly call them.

Comment: If you have control of the source of `SimpleObject` you could add an "increment" method, making sure it is executed atomically. Maybe have a look at [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) (and its siblings).

Comment: The increment is just an example for the way variables of the same type get passed that are working with numerical operations. I have control over `SimpleObject`. Also to mention that in the setter/getter methods logic can happen.

Comment: Of course, this would have to be taken into account for such convenience methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As geert3 said there is no shortcut to setters/getters in Java without accessing the property directly.

In your case your `SimpleObject`-class should just have a method `increaseCounter()` and maybe `increaseCounterBy(int add)` (or simply `add(int a)`).

Comment: I think ill stick with the `increaseCounterBy` solution, as it looks like a good tradeoff for not using xtend but to simply make visible that there is a self addition going on in the background.

Answer (score 3):

You have C# background I can imagine ;-)

It's not possible in Java (apart from not-quite-the-same solutions such as having public properties etc). Same as operator overloading, which could also have solved your issue.

However have a look at http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/ though, it's a JVM language similar to Java that supports operator overloading and some other nifty things.

Comment: I have some, yes. And i simply couldn't belive something so helpful was not possible in Java. So normally the way to go is to use the xtend JVM dialect?

Comment: I wouldnt say this is the way to go. Its just an option to consider if you have the freedom to do so. For most of us the way to go is to just live with the fact that this is not possible. An increment method is imo a nice way to work around the concrete issue here

Comment: Also, and this is probably a religious discussion, I don't really like concept of C#'s getters/setters "disguised" as properties, unless in very specific cases. In general it is confusing. I tend to miss it (and the operator overloading) in te context of language conversion (e.g. converting COBOL to Java where a "+" needs to do more than just the Java addition, or you want to add two non-native types. It really remains a plus, conceptually.

Comment: For my case, im afraid i cant migrate to xtend, because the operator overloading is just a minor fragment of the whole and for that changing form vanilla java to xtend might be to heavy. Also if youre working in a team, they have to learn the dialect too.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, I create annotation

```
/**
 * Annotation for PropertiesContainer class (that has field without getter and setter)
 * This class look like as class with Properties in C#
 *
 */
public @interface PropertiesContainer {
}
```

Add add to any class (annotation shows that isn't error)

```
@PropertiesContainer // class without getter and setter 
public Class SomeObject{
     public int counter;
}
```

And just use:

```
oSimple.counter++;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `value` doesn't have to be checked for any wrong values / execute code when setting it, you could solve it by just referencing the variable directly:

```
public Class SomeObject{
     public int value;
}

public Class Main{

     public static void main(String[] args){
          SomeObject o = new SomeObject();
          o.value += 1;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the example you gave is all you want to do (increment and assign an index for a new object every time you make one) then a common practice is use a static variable as a counter and a local variable for the specific index.

```
class SomeObject {

    static int objectCounter;
    private int index;

    public SomeObject() {
       index = objectCounter++;
       // additional constructor code
    }
}
```

If you wish to add a number to a variable, I'd consider making a separate method that does just that rather than trying to rewrite set(), or if it makes sense, make it part of the code for the set().